# How to Solve 01810. 00000 - "format code appears twice"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to sql.I am trying to get the records between two dates. But i am getting ORA-01810 error

Query:

```
SELECT txnid as txnid,
       to_date(txn_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as txn_date, 
       amount as amount 
  FROM transactionsdata ct 
 where ct.txn_date >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') 
   and ct.txn_date <= TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-27 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

What is wrong in my code?

This is the my table date format: `11-07-18 01:05:17.395000000 PM`

Comment: Your timestamp format pattern in the WHERE clause is wrong and different to the correct timestamp format pattern in column TXN_DATE

Comment: If `txn_date` is a timestamp as suggested by the `where` clause, what is the `to_date()` doing in the `select` list? You can't `to_date` a timestamp.

Comment: @William Robertson yes i removed `to_date()` in select.Now i am getting date like `11-07-18 01:05:17.395000000 PM` but i want `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` format that's why i used `to_date()` in select

Comment: Then you're converting a timestamp to a character string in a specified format, so `to_char()`

Comment: @William Robertson  you are suggesting `to_char()` replace of `to_date()` ?

Comment: @Durga yes. As Williams said, instead of to_date() use to_char().

Comment: @Durga yes - you "format" dates, timestamps and numbers by converting them to character strings in a specified format, so `to_char` is the function to use. All `to_date` does is make something into a `date`, which doesn't dictate any particular display format.

Comment: Thank you William Robertson and Goran Kutlaca it's working fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
SELECT txnid as txnid,
       to_char(txn_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as txn_date, 
       amount as amount 
  FROM transactionsdata ct 
   and ct.txn_date >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss') 
   and ct.txn_date <= TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-27 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss')
```

To represent minutes you have to use *mi*. You used it in your line 2 of code, bit not later.

Comment: i tried but getting 01849. 00000 -  "hour must be between 1 and 12"`

Comment: @Durga - `mi` eliminates `ORA-01810` error. Also use `HH24` instead of `HH`. But best option is to use timestamp literal: `between timestamp '2018-07-01 00:00:00' and timestamp '2018-07-27 00:00:00'`

Comment: That is because hour must be between 1 and 12 when using HH format. You should change it to HH24:mi:ss if inputing 00:00:00.

Comment: @Durga I changed my code. Try with it and say if there is some other error or if everything is now fine.

Comment: As William implied in a comment on the question, the `to_date()` in the select list should probably be `to_char()`

Comment: @Durga as Williams and Alex pointed out, I have also changed to_date() to to_char() in my answer.

Comment: @Durga OK. I'll try to help you further. Can you please specify in what way is data wrong? What does it give you and what are you expecting/ needing.

Comment: @Goran Kutlaca Tq. In my table records on two date only `12-07-18 01:05:17.395000000 PM` and `11-07-18 01:05:17.395000000 PM`. I'm trying to get records only before 11-07-2018 records . my query `select txnid,txn_date,amount from transactiondetails where TXN_DATE>=TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss') and TXN_DATE<=TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-11 23:00:0','yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss');` but i am getting all records from table

Comment: @Durga So, your select is also returning data with `txn_date = 12-07-18 01:05:17.395000000 PM` ?

Comment: @Goran Kutlaca yes

Comment: @Durga what happens when you add second `0` to your `23:00:0` so that it becomes `23:00:00` ?

Comment: @Goran Kutlaca no. I have 20 records table 15 records are `11-07-18 01:05:17.395000000 PM` date and 5 records are `12-07-18 01:05:17.395000000 PM` date. when i run query i get 20 records with `11-07-18 01:05:17.395000000 PM` date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177714/discussion-between-goran-kutlaca-and-durga).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you seem to want:

```
SELECT txnid as txnid,
       to_date(txn_date, 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS.FF9 AM') as txn_date, 
       amount as amount 
FROM transactionsdata ct 
WHERE ct.txn_date >= DATE '2018-07-01' AND 
      ct.txn_date <= DATE '2018-07-27'
```